# ios/objective-c: Testing for existence of NSUserDefault

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsuserdefaults

I wish to test whether an NSUserDefault value has been defined and if not define it.  However, in the case where the value of the variable is 0 which I think is the same as NO, the following is resolving to TRUE and resetting the variable.

```
if(![[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"notifyOn"]){
         [prefs setBool:YES forKey:@"notifyOn"];
    }
```

In other words, ![[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"notifyOn"] appears to be true if the value is 0.

I only want to set the variable if it has not been previously set.

As an aside, when I log this to the console, I am viewing 1 and 0 instead of YES and TRUE.  Am assuming they are the same, but if not, please confirm.

Thanks for help with this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All values, including primitive types like `BOOL`, are actually stored as objects (an `NSNumber` object, in the case of `BOOL`) and objects can be `nil`, meaning "not set".

Therefore:

```
if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"notifyOn"] == nil) {
    // Value is neither YES or NO
    // (same as setObject:@(YES) forKey:@"notifyOn")
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:@"notifyOn"];
}
```

Answer (score 3):

as for 0 and 1 yes they are equivalent to NO and YES. So you are following the right approach.

If you want to check the existence of boolean value then `[userDefaults boolForKey:@"theKeyOfMyBOOL"];` returns a BOOL, so either YES or NO (not nil).

Internally, it is stored as an NSNumber. So, if you call

```
[userDefaults objectForKey:@"theKeyOfMyBOOL"];
```

you will be given an NSNumber, if you have ever stored anything, or nil, if you have not.

Comment: Thank you, I was setting my BOOL with setBoolForKey and getting it back with objectForKey, so my if condition was always true and I couldn't understand why.